# Write down a partial differential equation satisfied by the function $g$.

Tags: analysis

Let $f$ be a differentiable function of one variable and let $g$ be t he function of two variables given by $g(x,y)=f(ax+by)$,where $a,b$ are fixed non-zero numbers.  Write down a partial differential equation satisfied by the function $g$.

Comment: by satisfy do you mean $$b\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}-a\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = 0$$

Comment: I dont think so..

Comment: kindly give details.. this is the answer.@Chinny84

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to my comment I just assuming I am trying to find an operator in terms of partials that yield zero. But this is just a standard change of co-ordinate technique..
$$
\partial_x g = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial u},\\
\partial_y g = \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}.
$$
where $u = ax + by$
and
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = a,\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = b.
$$
therefore
$$
\partial_x g = af'\implies b\partial_x g  = baf'\\
\partial_y g = bf'\implies a\partial_y g  = abf'.
$$
subtract the two resulting equations to yeild
$$
b\partial_x g - a\partial_y g = baf' - abf' = 0
$$
thus
$$
b\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} - a\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = 0
$$